# Unable Color Code Points on GeoPanda Map with Contextly Background Map

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I am trying to create a Map that has points that are color coded by a category - however when I color by category the index is being included in the category so every point is its own color.  Here is some sample code to recreate my problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import cm
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import contextily as ctx

list = [[39.17413494, -84.36475604, 'BK'],
 [38.96151336, -84.55732482, 'McDonalds'],
 [38.95100498, -84.55013050000001, 'McDonalds'],
 [38.96186501, -84.55717946, 'McDonalds'],
 [39.00969774, -84.50139703, 'Subway'],
 [39.09614656, -84.56445953, 'Pizza Hut'],
 [38.98661028, -84.39965444, 'Popeyes'],
 [39.34727542, -84.66033389, 'Arbys'],
 [39.09854089, -84.55881323, 'Wendys'],
 [39.0985409, -84.55881323, 'Subway'],
 [38.98693673, -84.39936496, 'Starbucks'],
 [39.17663372, -84.66664250000001, 'ChickFilA'],
 [39.19368097, -84.67709306, 'Subway'],
 [39.202496000000004, -84.5474509, 'Starbucks'],
 [39.202496000000004, -84.5474509, 'Starbucks'],
 [39.05680444, -84.32690772, 'BK'],
 [39.049786100000006, -84.39536650000001, 'McDonalds'],
 [39.049786100000006, -84.39536650000001, 'McDonalds'],
 [39.049786100000006, -84.39536650000001, 'McDonalds'],
 [39.049786100000006, -84.39536650000001, 'Subway'],
 [39.049786100000006, -84.39536650000001, 'Pizza Hut'],
 [39.04982251, -84.39533805, 'Popeyes'],
 [39.04982249, -84.39533811, 'Arbys'],
 [39.04982581, -84.39533835, 'Wendys'],
 [39.04982419, -84.39533558, 'Subway'],
 [39.04982533, -84.39534599, 'Starbucks'],
 [39.04982604, -84.39534769, 'ChickFilA'],
 [39.356410100000005, -84.361086, 'Subway'],
 [39.18283407, -84.38227921, 'Starbucks'],
 [39.43731072, -84.26926351, 'Starbucks']]
data = pd.DataFrame(list, columns =['Lat', 'Long', 'Type']) 

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(data['Long'], data['Lat'])]
crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'}
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('Dark2', 9)

gdf = gdf.to_crs(epsg=3857)
ax = gdf.plot(c=gdf.Type, cmap=cmap, label=gdf.Type, figsize=(10,10), alpha=.5)
ctx.add_basemap(ax, url=ctx.providers.Stamen.TonerLite)
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

Which results in the following image:

[image]

As you can see each "McDonalds" is its own color and the legend lists each data point.

Comment: I believe this related to known bug in geopandas 0.5.1 (and below) rather than error in your code. It has been fixed in 0.6 which has been released couple of days ago. Try updating Geopandas.

Comment: Thanks @martinfleis although it looks like I currently have geopandas-0.6.0 so either the bug still exists, or something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect attributes for plot. Geopandas (at least in recent versions) needs `column` not `c`.

```
ax = gdf.plot(column=gdf.Type, cmap=cmap, label=gdf.Type, figsize=(10,10), alpha=.5)
```

This seems to work. But you should be aware that you have multiple overlapping points, so it does not look the same all the time.

EDIT: to have proper legend, you need to use Geopandas to draw it and pass legend_kwds to Geopandas `plot`:

```
ax = gdf.plot(column=gdf.Type, cmap=cmap, label=gdf.Type,
              figsize=(10,10), alpha=.5, legend=True,
              legend_kwds={'loc': 'center left', 'bbox_to_anchor': (1, 0.5)})
ctx.add_basemap(ax, url=ctx.providers.Stamen.TonerLite)
ax.set_axis_off()
```

Comment: Even with changing to 'column' I am still not getting the 9 individual colors in the legend.  Understand the overlapping points, this was just some randomly generated data to illustrate the problem.

Comment: It works now ... thank you, was racking my brain on this one.  Appreciate the help @martinfleis